# How do I get the REST API's enabled for interacting in a Hyperledger fabric peer node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying out the Hyperledger fabric [Chaincode for Developers tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html). The CLI chaincode commands to deploy and invoke the chaincode is working.

How can I enable the REST API as in the Fabric Documentation [here](http://fabricrepo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/API/CoreAPI/#rest-api) or [here](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#rest-api). The link provided in the documentation https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/peer/core.yaml is not found currently.

Comment: Currently using Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from version 1.0.0 Hyperledger Fabric no longer expose REST API to interact the peers. Instead you have set of SDK which encapsulates interaction protocol allowing you to implement client logic which. At the moment you can take a look on following SDKs:

1. [NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)
2. [Golang SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)
3. [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)
4. [Python SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py)

And documentation you are referring is from v0.6 which is no longer relevant, please use updated [one here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The section of [chaincode for developers](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html) might be very useful for your case.

Comment: Thank you @Artem Barger. Just Curious, why they removed the REST API Support. I can see the JIRA task / Story : https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABR-4 and also, https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/admin/repos/fabric-sdk-rest. By removing the REST API Support, what advantages they get? Form my side, previously we have to use certificates, get context and then execute chain code, i think is more secure. What do you think from your side, please want to hear.